# displaying continuous output in the RGUI in R

Tags: r

I have a R program that produces ongoing sequential outputs that I want to display continuously in the RGUI console. However I need to keep pressing the return button
to keep seeing the next outputs. How can I avoid this? Strangely the problem does not happen when I run the program from within RStudio

many thanks
alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flush.console()` any time you want the console output to update. Example:

This will only print the output to the console at the end of the loop:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
    Sys.sleep(1)
    print(i)
}
```

This will print the output at each iteration of the loop:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
    Sys.sleep(1)
    print(i)
    flush.console()
}
```

Comment: Great, glad it works! You should accept the answer so other users can find it when they search for something like this.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance.How do I accept your answer?

Comment: There should be a check mark to the left of the answer area - clicking it means "this is the correct and best solution" and will mark the question as answered when it comes up in search results.